# Why does xcode's "go to definition" offer multiple options even though only one is correct?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, react-native, definition

I want to find the definition of the "initWithDelegate" constructor, so I right clicked on "go to definition"

Why does it show me multiple candidates, if i'm inside the @implementation block of RCTBridge, therefore "self" refers to RCTBridge class? And how did it find the other candidate? It scanned through the whole code base to find methods with the same signature from all different classes?[image]

Comment: `RCTCxxBridge` is a subclass of `RCTBridge`?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad yes, it is

Comment: Xcode doesn't know the class of `self` at runtime and shows a list of all possible definitions. Apparently Xcode goes up to the highest superclass which defines the method and then down to all subclasses of this superclass in the project. At the top is a search field to find a class in a long list.